# how to set a row's value from a certain row's value?

Tags: mysql, update

I have a MySQL table named "activities" with fields id(int), tstamp(timestamp), amount(decimal) balance(decimal). Decimal fields hold money values.

```
id   tstamp                   amount   balance
----------------------------------------------
 1   2013-03-18 00:00:10       57.00      0.00
 2   2013-03-18 00:00:11       13.05      0.00
 3   2013-03-18 00:00:12      110.00      0.00
 4   2013-03-18 00:00:13       23.50      0.00
 5   2013-03-18 00:00:14       35.44      0.00
 6   2013-03-18 00:00:15       76.00      0.00
 7   2013-03-18 00:00:16       34.74      0.00
 8   2013-03-18 00:00:17      120.47      0.00
 9   2013-03-18 00:00:18       35.00      0.00
10   2013-03-18 00:00:09       46.00      0.00
```

so balance fields' values must be like that:
current row's balance = **CHRONOLOGICALLY previous** row's balance + current row's amount.

Notice last row's tstamp value is smaller than first row's tstamp value. so when I say previous row I do not mean current id minus 1. So highest balance value must be at row #9.

And the problem is how to update all balances with chronogically previous row's balance value + current row's amount value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the `tstamp` has a `UNIQUE` constraint:

```
UPDATE activities AS a
  JOIN
  ( SELECT cur.tstamp,
           SUM(prev.amount) AS balance 
    FROM activities AS cur
      JOIN activities AS prev
        ON prev.tstamp <= cur.tstamp
    GROUP BY cur.tstamp
  ) AS p
  ON p.tstamp = a.tstamp
SET a.balance = p.balance ;
```

Tested: **[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/65070/1)**

---

MySQL has also a feature to use `ORDER BY` with an `UPDATE`, which you can combine with the use of variables:

```
SET @b := 0 ;
UPDATE activities
SET balance = (@b := amount + @b)
ORDER BY tstamp ;
```

Tested: **[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/710a4/1)**

Comment: Both works like a charm. Especially second query is fantastic. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

I'm AFK, and I can't read my SSH client on my phone, so I haven't tested this, but this is adapted from a similar scenario I have, although it's a `SELECT` rather than an `UPDATE`.  IOW, test it out, but this should get you on the right track:

```
UPDATE activities a1
SET a1.balance = a1.amount + (
    SELECT balance 
    FROM activities a2
    WHERE a2.tstamp < a1.tstamp
    ORDER BY a2.tstamp DESC
    LIMIT 1
) prev_balance;
```

My concern with this is that each balance has to be done in chronological order for this to work; with your example data, the row with id = 10 would have to be done FIRST, then the record with id = 1 etc.  AFAIK you can't force the order in which an update will occur, so you may have to execute this update against each row, stepping through with a cursor.

**EDIT**

The error is because you can't select directly from an update target in MySQL.  I can't see a way to do this without a cursor, since you need to make sure the rows are updated in chronological order.  Assuming this is an operation that you are performing only once, I'd read everything into a temp table in chronological order, then step through it with a cursor and update the table `activities` accordingly.

Comment: When i use exactly same query it gives a syntax error at 'prev_balance' part. When i remove this part then it gives that error: #1093 You can't specify target table 'a1' for update in FROM clause.